# How to change the day of the week?

Tags: datetime, postdate

Good day!

I display the day of the week on the site {{ now|date("l") }}

How to change for example Monday to Mondays (on Mondays)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking how to output the day of the week as _plural_?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're asking how to add a letter 's' to the day.
So how about using

```
{{ now|date("l") }}s
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the `defaultWeekStartDay` setting in your `config/general.php` -> https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#defaultweekstartday

Comment: Please tell me exactly how you can change the example: on Wednesdays using this setting?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question. It sounds like you're asking for how to display the days in plural form?

Comment: yes: on Wednesdays, Thursdays, Saturdays, etc.